# How to deserialize an anonymous abstract class with Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, anonymous-class

I've recently started to use Jackson as a friend recommend it, so I decided to create this Item object so I could play around with serializing and deserializing, though I occur an exception with the abstract class when deserializing. The Item object listed here

```
public static abstract class Item implements Saveable, Serializable, Useable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 45612874562156L;
    private final String nameId;
    String name;
    String description;
    int value;
    public Item(String name, String description, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nameId = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public void use() {}
    @Override
    public void save(Path directory) {
        save(directory, nameId, Prefix.SHOP, this);
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() { return description; }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

The Saveable interface consists of

```
public interface Saveable {

    ObjectMapper SAVEMAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    void save(Path outputDirectory);

    default <T extends Serializable, E extends Enum<E>> void save(Path outputDirectory, long id, E prefixType, T object) {
        save(outputDirectory, String.valueOf(id), prefixType, object);
    }
    default <T extends Serializable, E extends Enum<E>> void save(Path outputDirectory, String id, E prefixType, T object) {
        outputDirectory.toFile().mkdir();
        try {
            SAVEMAPPER.writeValue(Paths.get(outputDirectory.toString(), id+prefixType.toString()+".json").toFile(), object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveFileException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    static <T, E extends Enum<E>> T load(Path outputDirectory, String id, E prefixType, Class<? extends T> clazz) throws CouldNotLoadFileException {
        try {
            SAVEMAPPER.enableDefaultTyping();
            return SAVEMAPPER.readValue(Paths.get(outputDirectory.toString(), id+prefixType.toString()+".json").toFile(), clazz);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new CouldNotLoadFileException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    static <T, E extends Enum<E>> T load(Path outputDirectory, long id, E prefix, Class<? extends T> clazz) throws CouldNotLoadFileException {
        return load(outputDirectory, String.valueOf(id), prefix, clazz);
    }
    class CouldNotLoadFileException extends RuntimeException {
            CouldNotLoadFileException(String desciption) {
                super("Could not load file\n" + desciption);
            }
    }
    class CouldNotSaveFileException extends RuntimeException {
        CouldNotSaveFileException(String desciption) {
            super("Could not save file\n" + desciption);
        }
    }
}
```

The Useable interface is just an abstract method called use().
I have no problem serializing it, so when I do `new Item("Foo", "Bar", 10){}.save()` it serializes correctly (*i would assume*) to `{"name":"Foo","description":"Bar","value":10}`
That's great and all, but during deserialization I encounter this exception

```
me.James.misc.Saveable$CouldNotLoadFileException: Could not load file
Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class me.James.commands.GiftShop$Item
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 1]

    at me.James.misc.Saveable.load(Saveable.java:31)
    at me.James.commands.GiftShopSpec.creating, saving, and loading an item(GiftShopSpec.groovy:16)
```

When trying to Google around for the answer for this I tried enabling default type which returns the same exception, and trying to implement your own deserializer. I couldn't really find a great source to show how to create your own deserializer. That believes me to believe its probably something with implementing your own deserializer by extending the StdDeserializer but I can't really figure out how. I expect to return a Item when doing `Saveable.load(Paths.get("./data", "other", "shop"), "Testing", Prefix.SHOP, GiftShop.Item.class)` but at the moment I get an exception. I test all of this in this Spock test

```
class GiftShopSpec extends Specification {
    void "creating, saving, and loading an item"() {
        given: "an item with example values"
        GiftShop.Item sampleItem = new GiftShop.Item("Testing", "Test", 5) {}
        and: "saving the item"
        sampleItem.save(Paths.get("./data", "other", "shop"))
        when: "we load the item from disk"
        GiftShop.Item loadedItem = Saveable.load(Paths.get("./data", "other", "shop"), "Testing", Prefix.SHOP, GiftShop.Item.class);
        then: "we get an item from disk"
        sampleItem == loadedItem
    }
}
```

If the problem is that I'm not creating my own custom deserializer than a resource on how to implement one would be great. I'm writing this all in Java 10 and Jackson version 2.9.7. Thanks for your time and hope I could provide all information needed.

Comment: welcome to SO, please add exceptions/errors as part of a question and not as an image or link to other sites.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see an image? I did use an hyperlink to a hastebin though.

Comment: Have a look this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/  to ask an effective question

Comment: Oh thank you. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the deserializer doesn't know what kind of class should it create from the JSON string. The class argument you pass it is an abstract class and you cannot instantiate an abstract class in java.

You have to tell the objectmapper the type of the desired class. Use `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation on Item.class, that will store the additional type-info in the JSON string.

But unfortunately it still not enough, because the anonymous inner class has only a temporary object-type, it cannot be seen outside of the method, so even its type info is stored in the JSON string, it cannot be restored later.

So you have to define the actual class at-least as an inner class. And you still  have to define how to store the type-information.

There is a very good guide about it here:

[Inheritance with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)

Comment: Thank you so much, Selindek i’ll have a look at the post you mentioned. Cheers!